# changing location.hash with jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, fragment-identifier

I've been trying to find a way to change the window.location.hash to the currently selected tab in [Jquery UI Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs).

I've tried:

```
$("#tabs > ul").tabs();
$("#tabs > ul").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui) { 
window.location.hash = ui.tab;
})
```

This results in changing the hash to #undefined when the tab is changed.

I've also tried:

```
$("#tabs > ul").tabs({ 
select: function(event, ui) { 
window.location.hash = ui.tab }
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be triggered at all.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:  It looks like part of my initial problem had something to do with js somewhere else interfering with this.  Both the accepted answer and the other suggested answer slightly modified do work.  Thanks all.

Comment: are you trying to open a link in the tab where the link clicked from ?

Comment: No, the links I'm opening are part of the current page itself, no ajax/etc.

Comment: this is a pretty awesome demo of this technique:
[http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/)

Comment: Is there a workaround that prevents the page from jumping down to that hash anchor in the page when a tab is clicked?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In your event handler function `ui.tab` is an anchor element. You can retrieve its hash value like this:

```
$("#tabs > ul").tabs();
$("#tabs > ul").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui) { 
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
})
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I receive many ui.tab is undefined errors upon page load or tab change.

Comment: I've been trying with the demo that appears on the doc page and works fine with FF 3 and IE 7. Are you triggering the events manually?

Comment: I tried as you suggested with the demo page and your solution did end up working, thanks for the solution, I'll have to figure out what else in my code was stopping it from working.  Thanks

Comment: If you are testing on Firefox, install the Firebug extension and put a console.trace() to track where the problems come from.

Answer (score 25):

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

While some of the above solutions work, they cause the page to jump around in some cases, as the window.location.hash API is designed to bring you to a specific part of the page.

This neat solution proposed [here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/), solves that issue

```
  $("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui) { 
    history.pushState(null, null, ui.tab.hash);
  });
```

Comment: This should probably be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, jQuery UI 1.10:

```
$('#elexumaps_events_tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) { 
       window.location.hash=ui.newPanel.selector; 
    }
});
```

See also: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: this works well for me, however, I'm using ajax to load my tabs, so the hash is always "ui-tabs-1", "ui-tabs-2", etc...  This means when I re-order, add, or remove tabs the bookmarks break.  Do you know a way to do this where I can use custom hash names for the tabs?

Answer (score 7):

my simple solution without jumping:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.selector;
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Would this be what you're going for?

```
$("#tabs > ul").tabs({ 
   select: function(event, ui) 
   { 
      window.location = "#" + ui.tab;
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried this without any luck.  I even tried putting an alert prior to the window.location setting and it doesn't appear when changing tabs.  The only way I could get it to activate was by binding tabsshow but that ends up with an undefined ui.tab

Comment: When I tried using the demo code this solution slightly modified did work.  The only change I would suggest is making it:
window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;

Comment: This worked as the best solution for me. Other suggestions resulted in the page jumping to the tab selected when the location hash was updated. Seconding "window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;" in place of what is provided in the example, tho.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the above answers don't work with the current version of jQuery UI Tabs. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
var tabsUi = $('#tabs');
tabsUi.tabs();

// Add hash to URL when tabs are clicked
tabsUi.find('> ul a').click(function() {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
});

// Switch to correct tab when URL changes (back/forward browser buttons)
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    if (location.hash !== '') {
        var tabNum = $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').parent().index();
        tabsUi.tabs('option', 'active', tabNum);
    } else {
        tabsUi.tabs('option', 'active', 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect solution, the only one that worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
      window.location = ui.tab.href;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

My way for jQuery UI 1.10.3

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        var hash = ui.newTab.children("li a").attr("href");
        window.location.hash = hash;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a tab plugin you can find it at github: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools.github.com

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using Jquery 1.8

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
       window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking through some other questions and the jQueryUI API docs I found that this ended up working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            location.hash = ui.newTab.children(".ui-tabs-anchor").attr("href").substr(1);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ui.tab itself doesn't return a valid string. (instead it returns undefined, so you'd say it doesn't return anything at all.)

Try looking around in the dev version of ui.jquery.js whether there are any returns there, maybe you have to call a child of ui.tab ;-)

Comment: @Fabdrol you need ui.tab.index ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code works ok for me:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        window.location = $(ui.tab).attr('href');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) { 
       window.location.hash=ui.newPanel.selector; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is worked for me..

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   activate : function(event, ui) {
     window.location.hash = ui.newPanel[0].id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My working solution.

jQuery v3.5.1, jQuery UI v1.12.1

```
$(".detail-groups").tabs({ activate: function(event, ui) {
                            window.location.hash = ui.newPanel[0].id;
                         }
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code worked for me:

```
window.location.hash="";
```