# jQuery tabs (how come clicking tab doesnt show hash on URL?)

Tags: jquery, hash, tabs

I am using jQuery tabs but when I click a tab, the hash doesnt appear on the browser URL. Is there a way to get it there? An option I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hash using Javascript

```
document.location.hash = "blahblahblah";
```

EDIT: Ah, you are using jQuery, I wonder if this answer will help you...
[changing location.hash with jquery ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570276/changing-location-hash-with-jquery-ui-tabs)