# Chrome: XHR finished loading, return XHR as string?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm wondering.. how would I get the `XHR finished loading` string?

Basically, I'm on Google instant's page and I want to get the return the "real" URL of the search results in the form of a string.

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for a bit more?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the response of the request?

Comment: So this is actually the same as you previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850349/window-location-force-to-update If you don't provide a detailed description of your problem, you won't get good answers. Don't let us guess, be specific.

Comment: It's not so much the same.. this is an extension to my last question.

Comment: @Skizit: But what is the difference? It seems to be the same goal: Get the "real" URL. Or am I missing something? If the questions are 98% the same that you should edit and clarify your original question instead of creating a new one. I asked a couple of questions about your previous question and you did not even bother to answer them. Don't expect help from us if you don't help us to help you.

Comment: @Felix Kling I didn't see your reply to the other question. I have responded and voted to close this question.

Comment: As I understand you want to monitor ajax requests that are being made by google and get notified when such request finishes. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option, you can do an Ajax call and get the result of the page in the succes event

```
    $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: did you include jquery and stuff?